# How to exclude package in given runtime profile in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, profile

In my application I have two profiles `dev` and `prod`, I can exclude beans using `org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile` annotation:

```
package com.example.prod;

@Service
@Profile("prod")
public class MyService implements MyBaseService {}
```

The problem is, I have several beans which are annotated in such way, all of them are in same package `com.example.prod`. Similar structure exists for `dev` profile (`com.example.dev` package), and may in future I will have some additional profiles. Is there possibility to exclude whole package at once? I tried to play with `org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan`, but I was unable to add exclude filters depends on actual profile, I wonder if there is easy way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement a custom [TypeFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/type/filter/TypeFilter.html) to disable `ComponentScan` for certain packages based on the active profile . A kick-start example is :

(1) Implement the Filter. For demo purpose , I hard codes that if the active profile is `dev` , it will exclude the package configured by `devExcludePackage` property. For `prod` profile , it will exclude the package configured by `prodExcludePackage`   :

```
public class ExcludePackageTypeFilter implements TypeFilter , EnvironmentAware  {

    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public boolean match(MetadataReader metadataReader, MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory)
            throws IOException {

        boolean match = false;
        for (String activeProfile : env.getActiveProfiles()) {
            if (activeProfile.equals("dev")) {
                match = isClassInPackage(metadataReader.getClassMetadata(), env.getProperty("devExcludePackage"));
            } else if (activeProfile.equals("prod")) {
                match = isClassInPackage(metadataReader.getClassMetadata(), env.getProperty("prodExcludePackage"));
            }
        }
        return match;
    }

    private boolean isClassInPackage(ClassMetadata classMetadata, String pacakage) {
        return classMetadata.getClassName().startsWith(pacakage);
    }


    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.env = environment;
    }
}
```

(2) Configure `application.properties` to define which packages to exclude for different profiles.

```
devExcludePackage  = com.example.prod
prodExcludePackage = com.example.dev
```

(3) Apply this filter to `@ComponentScan` :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
                type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = { ExcludePackageTypeFilter.class }))
public class Application {


}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was looking for, maybe not super elegant, but works. BTW. `devPackage` and `prodPackage` should have opposite values I think, you've defined which packages you want to exclude, so `devPackage` should exclude `com.example.prod` and `prodPackage=com.example.dev`. But anyway, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are right , and I Just change to use some better name for these properties :P

Comment: It does not work for external classes e.g. MongoDataAutoConfiguration (which would work if put as exclude in @SpringBootApplication.